# ParserError: Expected ',' but got '}'

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, blockchain, remix

I saw similar questions, but my problem is not matching any of those answered questions. I've written a function in a library that also includes in-assembly code but getting an unexpected parser error.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity ^0.8.11;

library CryptoSuite {

    function splitSignature(bytes memory _sign) internal pure returns(uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) {
        
        require(_sign.length == 65);

        //accessing virtual machine to make low level changes.
        assembly {

            //first 32 bytes
            r := mload(add(_sign, 32))
            //next 32 bytes
            s := mload(add(_sign, 64))
            //last 32 bytes
            v := byte(0, mload(add(_sign, 96))
            
        } //getting error here in remix. 

        return (v, r, s);
        
    }

    //split Signature, recieve signature for message, extract signer from that message

    function recoverSigner(bytes32 _message, bytes memory _sign) internal pure returns(address){
        //first get values

        (uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) = splitSignature(_sign);

        return ecrecover(_message, v, r, s);

    } 

}
```

The error says `ParserError: Expected ',' but got '}'` Please anyone help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a missing closing bracket in the following line
`v := byte(0, mload(add(_sign, 96))`. The line should end with ")))".

```
v := byte(0, mload(add(_sign, 96)))
```